# Mapbox GL JS getBounds()/fitBounds()

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox GL JS v0.14.2 and I've searched high and low through the documentation and very little is clear about this.

If you use the standard JS API, it's very clear to 'fit map to markers' using an example they have provided (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/fit-map-to-markers/); however the setup when using the GL api is quite different. The GL API has `getBounds()` (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map.getBounds) but because you don't have a named layer, like the standard JS API, so I'm struggling to work out how to use `getBounds()` at all.

I've found this ([Mapbox GL JS API Set Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281106/mapbox-gl-js-api-set-bounds)) but surely can't be the right answer?

This is the bulk of my setup; excluding JSON setup and other options.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<myaccesstoken>';

var markers = <?php echo $programme_json; ?>;

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/richgc/cikyo5bse00nqb0lxebkfn2bm',
    center: [-1.470085, 53.381129],
    zoom: 15
});

map.on('style.load', function() {
    map.addSource('markers', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': markers
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "markers",
        "interactive": true,
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "markers",
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "venue-map-icon-blue",
            'icon-size': 0.5,
            "icon-allow-overlap": true
        }
    });

    map.scrollZoom.disable();

});
```

I have tried the following:

```
alert(map.getBounds()); // LngLatBounds(LngLat(-1.4855345239256508, 53.37642500812015), LngLat(-1.4546354760740883, 53.38583247227842))
var bounds = [[-1.4855345239256508, 53.37642500812015],[-1.4546354760740883, 53.38583247227842]]
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

So I know how to fitBounds, but I'm unsure how to get them `map.getBounds()` just seems to return the set centre position lng/lat.

Markers JSON:

```
var markers = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"Site Gallery","url":"\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/site-gallery\/","summary":"Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Donec id justo. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Suspendisse feugiat. Etiam rhoncus.","image":"\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/site\/assets\/files\/1032\/site_gallery.jpg","marker-symbol":"venue-map-icon-blue","colour":"blue"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-1.466439","53.376842"]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"Moore Street Substation","url":"\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/moore-street-substation\/","summary":"","image":null,"marker-symbol":"venue-map-icon-green","colour":"green"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-1.477881","53.374798"]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"S1 Artspace","url":"\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/s1-artspace\/","summary":"","image":null,"marker-symbol":"venue-map-icon-red","colour":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-1.459620","53.380562"]}}]};
```

Comment: "map.getBounds() just seems to return the set centre position lng/lat" Isn't it returning the lower-left and upper-right coordinates of your bounding box?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

If you want to fit map to markers, you can create bounds that contains all markers.

```
var bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();

markers.features.forEach(function(feature) {
    bounds.extend(feature.geometry.coordinates);
});

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: This works! Is there anyway I can add padding to this?

Comment: Usually when fitBounds called, maps will to add padding to this bounds to prevent overlapping of map ui elements (like zoom plus/minus buttons, logo and etc) to bounds. It you want to add more padding, you can zoom out a map a little bit using `map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1)`, but it looks like a small hack.

Comment: Got padding to work with: `map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 100 });`

Comment: Just be aware, that fitBounds won't work with a single lat/long - so if you've only got one marker, your `bounds` object won't be useful (which does make sense).

Comment: This breaks for me when some geometries in a FeatureCollection are not points. Using turf.js envelope(), this worked for me: map.fitBounds(envelope(myfeaturecollection).bbox)

Comment: Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}....

Answer (score 22):

For a solution that will work for all GeoJSON objects, not just a set of markers, check out Mapbox's [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/).

This code was very helpful to me: https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/83a8ddff7fb9193176a975a02a896792

But just to repeat the basics in case that link dies:

```
var bounds = turf.bbox(markers);
map.fitBounds(bounds, {padding: 20});
```

The `extent` method mentioned in the linked code has been deprecated in favour of `bbox`, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 6):

Mapbox's own [geojson-extent](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-extent) plugin will do the trick. Assuming your `markers` object is [valid GeoJSON](https://www.mapbox.com/geojsonhint/), you can simply pass it to the `geojsonExtent()` function to get a set of bounds that you can then pass to `fitBounds()`.

Once you load the [geojson-extent.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapbox/geojson-extent/master/geojson-extent.js) file (e.g., by using a `<script>` tag in your HTML code), you should be able to do this to fit your map to the bounds of your GeoJSON `markers` object:

```
map.fitBounds(geojsonExtent(markers));
```

**UPDATE**

[GeoJSONLint](http://geojsonlint.com/) reports that your `markers` object is not valid GeoJSON because the elements in each position are being interpreted as strings, not numbers. If you remove the quotes from the lon-lat coordinates, it should work fine:

```js
var markers = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Site Gallery",
        "url": "\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/site-gallery\/",
        "summary": "Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Donec id justo. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Suspendisse feugiat. Etiam rhoncus.",
        "image": "\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/site\/assets\/files\/1032\/site_gallery.jpg",
        "marker-symbol": "venue-map-icon-blue",
        "colour": "blue"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.466439,
          53.376842
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Moore Street Substation",
        "url": "\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/moore-street-substation\/",
        "summary": "",
        "image": null,
        "marker-symbol": "venue-map-icon-green",
        "colour": "green"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.477881,
          53.374798
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "S1 Artspace",
        "url": "\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/s1-artspace\/",
        "summary": "",
        "image": null,
        "marker-symbol": "venue-map-icon-red",
        "colour": "red"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.459620,
          53.380562
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get this error in my console `Uncaught Error: Invalid LngLat object: (NaN, 1)` – I do believe that it is valid geoJSON as the map is working BUT I guess `markers` is returning more than just coordinates so perhaps I need to pass just the coordinates into the geojsonExtent.

Comment: And based on this example (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/static-map-from-geojson-with-geo-viewport/) which uses the static map and not the GL JS map, it seems my geoJSON is valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution based on the reduce operation from a [Mapbox example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/).

It works for geojson that contain point features and multi-point features like lines.

```js
let bounds = geoJSON.features.reduce(function(bounds, feature) {
  if(!Array.isArray(feature.geometry.coordinates[0])) { // point feature
    return bounds.extend(feature.geometry.coordinates);
  } else {
    return feature.geometry.coordinates.reduce(function(bounds, coord) {
      return bounds.extend(coord);
    }, bounds);
  }
}, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds());

map.fitBounds(bounds, {
  maxZoom: 12,
  padding: 30, // in px, to make markers on the top edge visible
})
```

Comment: how do I do this if I'm building my GeoJson as `map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource('points', {
       'type': 'geojson',
       'data': {
           'type': 'FeatureCollection',
           'features': [
        {` etc

Answer (score 1):

Improved solution (based on @timur solution) to handle large data-sets, by using while loop and promise

```
setBounds() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
                let i = 0;
                while (i < GEO_JSON.length) {
                    bounds.extend(GEO_JSON[i].geometry.coordinates/OR/Markers_ARRAY);
                    i++;
                }
                if (bounds) {
                    resolve(bounds);
                } else {
                    reject(`error:${  bounds}`);
                }
            });
        },

fitBoundsToMarkers() {
            this.setBounds().then((bounds) => {
                    map.fitBounds(bounds, {
                        padding: {
                            top: 100,
                            bottom: 100,
                            left: 100,
                            right: 100,
                        },
                        maxZoom: 14,
                    });
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the map edges cutting the markers, add +0.02 to HighestLng in getting North East coordinate and subtract 0.02 from lowestLng of South west coordinate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If anyone here is using [React-Map-GL](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl), has more than two markers, and wants to figure out the bounds ***before*** loading the map and retrieving the Mapbox instance you can do this:

```
const lat = myCoordinatesArray.map(location => parseFloat(location.lat));
const lng = myCoordinatesArray.map(location => parseFloat(location.lng));

// Note that WebMercatorViewport requires this format [lng, lat]
const minCoords = [Math.min.apply(null, lng), Math.min.apply(null, lat)];
const maxCoords = [Math.max.apply(null, lng), Math.max.apply(null, lat)];
const formattedGeoData = [minCoords, maxCoords];

const vPort = new WebMercatorViewport(this.state.viewport).fitBounds(formattedGeoData, {
  padding: 100
});

const { latitude, longitude, zoom } = vPort;
```

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40506115/1259863

You can do all this in the constructor way before the render function and get your values for the plugin init.